# How to pull down a list of domains using wget and scan them using grep

Tags: linux, shell, grep, wget

I have a list of domain names contained within a folder named "domains.txt", formatted like this:

```
www.google.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.apple.com
etc...
```

I want to perform a wget command to pull down a copy of each domain listed inside "domains.txt" and save it as a .html page.

I can do this individually using `wget www.google.com` but I'm wondering, instead of doing each one separately, can I iterate through the list and save each domain name as a separate .html file?

The second action I want to perform is a scan of these pulled down .html files for keywords, which I have contained in a text file named "keywords.txt". They're formatted like this:

```
first_keyword
second_keyword
third_keyword
etc...
```

Ideally, I'd like to have an output that prints the domain name to a text file, with a "yes" beside it if it has been found to contain any of the keywords contained in "keywords.txt". If it's possible to print what keywords were found beside each domain that would be brilliant, but a simple "yes" would be great too. I'm brand new to Linux and scripting, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com instead. SO is for programming questions only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the files don't contain the quotes. Otherwise I would need more code to remove the quotes.

domains.txt

```
www.google.com
www.stackoverflow.com
www.apple.com
```

keywords.txt

```
first_keyword
second_keyword
third_keyword
```

You can try something like this

```
outfile=tmp.html

while IFS= read -r domain
do
    wget -O "$outfile" "$domain"

    if fgrep -q -f keywords.txt "$outfile"
    then
        echo "$domain" yes
    else
        echo "$domain" no
    fi

    rm "$outfile"

done < domains.txt
```